# macOS - command not found: uvicorn

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, path, uvicorn

I bought a MAC and I use this system for the first time, I also recently started using python.
I have a python project with a requirement.txt file which I opened with PyCharm which also contains a dependency on uvicorn. I installed all the dependencies, but when I try to run the command "uvicorn main: app" I get the error "command not found: uvicorn".
I tried to look for guides on my problem and I read that it could concern the PATH variable and following what written in these guides I tried to add the PATH to python from my home directory. Now the content of my python PATH is the following:

> /Library/Python/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

I also read that I should have added the following line to my ~/.profile file and that because my MAC is a new one I could not have it, so I created this file and write the line written below:

> export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH

nothing has changed since my attempts so I am asking what I should do. I've also seen that pip3 installed my modules of the requirements.txt file on the following directory:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Did you `pip3 install uvicorn` or `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`?

Comment: I haven't installed the dependencies on requirements.txt from the command line. When I worked on the same project on windows PyCharm detected the requirements and installed them on its on. On mac it does not append so from the IDE I installed them one by one using the shortcut ALT-ENTER installe dependence. In this project is the first time I see the requirements file, so I did not know the possibility to use the command pip3 install -r requirements.txt

Comment: I tried now to use the command `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` but I obtained the following error: `no such option -r`

Comment: `-r` is correct. https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-r. Try manually installing the dependencies.

Comment: trying to write the command `pip3 install uvicorn` the terminal responds `Requirement already satisfied: uvicorn in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`, but still I receive command not found. when I write `uvicorn main:app`

Comment: Does `uvicorn --version` work?

Comment: No, it does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved setting a virtual environment in the project directory and installed the dependencies in it.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the "-m"

in this case:

```
python3 -m uvicorn main:app --reload --port 50000
```

If this works, you can find your sever at localhost:50000

Answer (score 6):

I am tried to install uvicorn:

```
pip3 install uvicorn
```

then run this command:

```
python3 -m uvicorn main:app --reload
```

works.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I added the virtual env and ran it with python3 (Trying FastAPI)

`python3 -m venv env`
`source env/bin/activate`
`pip install -r requirements.txt`
`python3 main.py`